# Diagnostic plots for lmer

Tags: r, lme4-nlme, validation, diagnostic, glmm

I am trying to produce a glmm using the `lme4` package in `R`. To validate my model I would like to produce some diagnostic plots but am having trouble doing so as many of the packages that work for `lm()` models like CAR do not work for `lmer()` models. I have tried using the `languageR` and `asuR` packages but am just getting errors. I am particularly interested in creating partial residual plots.

I have been able to produce qqplots, residual vs fitted plots and look at cooks distances manually. Any suggestions of further plots I should try or packages that would help would be greatly appreciated.

```
fm <- lmer(Average.payoff ~ Game + Type + Others.Type + Game*Type + Game*Others.Type +
  Type*Others.Type + (1|Subjects), REML=FALSE, data=Subjectsm1)

library(asuR)
inspect(fm)
Error in .setupMethodsTables(fdef, initialize = TRUE) : 
  no slot of name "group" for this object of class "derivedDefaultMethod"

library(languageR)
plotLMER.fnc(fm)
warning: I don't know how to handle  Game 
Error in preparePredictor.fnc(predictors[i], model, m, ylabel, fun, val = NA,  : 
  object 'dfr' not found
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider fitting your model using the "lme" function of the R-package "nlme" instead. The book "Mixed Effects Models in S and S-Plus" by Pinheiro & Bates contains a thorough description of the functionalities of the package, including a large variety of diagnostic plots.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. My model does appear to be suffering from a degree of heteroscedasticity which lme has a convenient method of handling so I think this may be a better option taking this also into account. I will in the near future be needing to model a binary response variable in which case I will need the lmer function, so any further suggestions would be useful.